# Select previously active tab in Firefox with Vimperator

Tags: firefox, vimperator

So I am on one of the pinned tabs, then I do `:t google something` it switches me to the new tab, and… How can I go back? Neither `gT` nor `gb` or `gB` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `C-6`.

You can bind that action to another key if you wish:

```
map <A-v> <C-6>
```

The doc says (chapter 9 of :help) there is `C-^` and that you can pass a numeric argument.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "H" for page back options and "L" page forward option.

check the link below for further more cheat sheet.

http://sheet.shiar.nl/vimperator

hope this helps

Comment: It does switching between history of one tab. Well nevermind, I’m not looking for the answer since I figured out that closing that tab with google switches me back automatically, and I wouldn’t keep it anyway. Let the question stay, maybe keeping the new tab and switching back would be important for somebody else :D